# If $~f~$ is continuous and $f(0)=\frac{\pi}{2},~$ $g(x)=\cos(f(x))$ is monotonically decreasing, then $~f~$ is uniformly continuous

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-continuity

> Let $~f,~g : \Bbb R \to \Bbb R~$, then show that if $f$ is continuous and $~f(0)=\frac{\pi}{2},~~g(x)=\cos(f(x))~$ is monotonically decreasing, then $~f~$ is uniformly continuous.

**My thought:**

I think we need to show that $f$ can be continuously extended. So, I tried to suppose $\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)$ dose not exist and induce a contradiction to the fact that $\cos(f(x))$ is monotone decreasing function... Could you please any hint to solve this problem by myself ?

I don't want you to show all proof.

Thank you.

Comment: Hint: What does $\cos(f(x))$ being monotonically decreasing tell us about the image of $f$?

Comment: $f(x)$ must be monotonically increasing, up to $\pi$.   then $f$ must converge to some number when x goes to infinity. is my thought right..?

Comment: Yes, it sounds like you've got it.

Comment: Don't forget the end at $-\infty$!

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen oh, thank your advice. I will try to show the other side.

Comment: @AlecB-G Thank you... !! I will try to solve again..!

Comment: fivestar.  $f$ must converge when $x \rightarrow \infty$, please elaborate.Thanks.